# interactive (adding listeners to) DAE model in flex + papervision

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, listener, papervision3d, collada

I have a DAE model that is parsed into several parts. I am able to deal with them separately, such as changing their material or colour but I am having problems adding click or hover listeners over the children.

For example, lets say I have a model of a kitty where each facial feature is a child. I want to be able to hover or click the features and have a window pop up explaining the feature.

I've tried parsing the model and adding listeners but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks in advance!

L

Answer (score 0):

Hard to pin point the problem from your description, but you could check the following:

1. Make sure your **viewport** is **interactive**
2. Make sure the **material** your material is **interactive**
3. Make sure the DisplayObject3D you assign the listener to is **not null**.

Point 3, with collada objects, you can have nested objects, make sure you add a listener to an object that has geometry, not an empty(no geometry) container. With points 1,2, both viewport and material have a Boolean property called interactive which must be set to true for mouse events.

HTH